# MySQL LEFT JOIN 3 tables, how to do it

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

```
warehouse(id,name)
article (id, name)
inventory(id,warehouse_id,article_id, quantity)
```

In articles I have 1000 articles, i  have 4 warehouse. Now in my table inventory i only have a record of 300 articules with only 2 warehouse. I want to get all articles with their all warehouse but i only can get 300 rows. I am trying left join but i cant get it.

```
For example i want this
article 1: 
warehouse 1:1000
warehouse 2:1000
warehouse 3:0  (beacuse there is no record in invetory)
warehouse 4:3000

article 2:  
warehouse 1:0 (beacuse there is no record in invetory)
warehouse 2:0 (beacuse there is no record in invetory)
warehouse 3:0 (beacuse there is no record in invetory)
warehouse 4:0 (beacuse there is no record in invetory)
```

Thanks, Sorry if the question already exists but I try those answers and I could not solve my problem

Comment: I see no warehouse_id in any other table.

Comment: yes, sorry, is bodega_id. I forgot to translate that part

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, 
       a.name as article_name, 
       w.name as warehouse_name
from article a
left join inventory i on i.article_id = a.id
left join warehouse w on i.warehouse_id = w.id
```